# Pass model to Jquery Dialog MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Ok so here is the scenario.  I have a grid view page with several fields on it.  I am trying to allow users to add a new field.  The users click the add new button and I load a Jquery dialog box with a new model that I prepopulate with some basic data that are the defaults of all fields, lets refer to this as dialog1 the model thats created lets call model1.  Within that dialog I am trying to launch another dialog that allows users to add drop down options if the field type is a drop down.  I want to pass the model1 that was created on the launch of dialog1 to dialog2 as a reference type so I am manipulating model 1.  I want to be able to add the drop down list items to model1 while on dialog2.  I can't get the model in the controller to get populated with any data from the original model, much less use it as a reference type.  Any help would be appreciated. I think the problem has to do with improper model binding. Here is the ajax call where I serialize the model and try to pass it to the controller.

```
var JsonModel = "@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model).Replace("\"", "\\\"").Replace("{", "[{").Replace("}", "}]"))";
    JsonModel = JsonModel.substr(JsonModel.length -JsonModel.length + 1, JsonModel.length - 2);


    // Add list items to drop down list fields
    $('#EditListOptions').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#AddListItemsModal").dialog({

            autoOpen: true,
            position: { my: "center", at: "top+350", of: window },
            width: 500,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Add List Item',
            dialogClass: 'no-close',
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("RetrieveAddListItemsView")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:  JsonModel,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#AddListItemsModal").html(data.htmlContent);
                    }
                });
            },
            buttons: {
                "Add Option": {
                    text: "Add Option",
                    id: "AddListItemButton",
                    class: "btn btn-primary",
                },
                Cancel: {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    class: "btn btn-default",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
```

Here is the controller.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RetrieveAddListItemsView(FormFieldEditModel JsonModel)
    {
        var content = base.SerializeView("AddListItems", JsonModel);
        return Json(new { success = true, data = JsonModel, htmlContent = content }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is the model

```
public class FormFieldEditModel
{
    public Guid FormFieldId { get; set; }
    public Guid FormId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Field Name")]
    public string FormFieldName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Display Text")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public int? X_Cord { get; set; }
    public int? Y_Cord { get; set; }
    public int? Size { get; set; }
    public int? Col_Count { get; set; }
    public int? Row_Count { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Required?")]
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Displayed?")]
    public bool IsDisplayed { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Field Type")]
    public Guid FieldTypeId { get; set; }
    public string FieldTypeName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> FieldTypes { get; set; }
    public List<DropDownListItemstModel> DropDownListOptions { get; set; }
    public string DropDownListDisplay { get; set; }
    public string DropDownListValue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Default Value")]
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Radio Button Group")]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Font Color")]
    public string ColorCode { get; set; }
    public int? Height { get; set; }
    public int? Width { get; set; }
    public int? TabIndex { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfForms { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email?")]
    public bool Email { get; set; }


    // other properties not saved with model
    public int FieldTypeCode { get; set; }
    public int? MinHeight { get; set; }
    public int? MinWidth { get; set; }
    public int Z_Index { get; set; }

    public string FormFieldOptionsJSON { get; set; }
    public List<FormFieldOptionEditModel> FormFieldOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You build an object representation, then transmit to a `JsonResult` with a parameter of said object, and MVC should attempt to properly designate the values for the model.

Comment: I kinda thought thats what I was doing here.
var JsonModel = "@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model).Replace("\"", "\\\"").Replace("{", "[{").Replace("}", "}]"))";
    JsonModel = JsonModel.substr(JsonModel.length -JsonModel.length + 1, JsonModel.length - 2);

Comment: The above basically just takes the model and converts it into a valid Json object.   Also I am passing to an action result controller and not a JsonResult.  Does that matter?  I thought those were just return types and not the type of incoming content.

Comment: i think you need to specify the name of the parameter, so data: { 'JsonModel': JsonModel } in your ajax call